# .net 5.0 Integration Test, Health check endpoint not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, health-check

I'm trying to test the health check endpoint.

I've implemented an integration test with .net core and WebApplicationFactory and TestServer, in order to test my API endpoints.

I wrote test cases(xUnit) to test my API endpoints, the simple API controllers work just fine, but it's not found the Health check endpoint - it is not a controller, it's a configurable endpoint

Here is the service configuration

```
services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<PingHealthCheck>("ping_health_check");
```

Here is the configuration

```
  endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
    {
        // Prevent response caching
        AllowCachingResponses = false,
        ResponseWriter = (context, report) => context.Response
            //Return an object instead of a plain text
            .WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {status= report.Status.ToString() })),
        ResultStatusCodes =
            {
                [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable
            }
    })
```

And here is the test case

```
[Fact]
public async Task Call_Health_Return_Healthy()
{
    //Arrange 
    //Act
    var response = await _factory.TestHttpClient
        .GetAsync("/health");
    //Assert
    response.StatusCode.Should().BeEquivalentTo(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If not, then what response are you getting?

Comment: What is `_factory`, `TestHttpClient` and `TestRoutesConstants.HealEndpoint`?

Comment: @mason I'm getting 404 status,

Comment: @GuruStron the _factory is an instance of WebApplicationFactory, and TestHttpClient is instance of TestServer.CreateClient()  and TestRoutesConstants.HealEndpoint is a string const = "/health" endpoint

Comment: @avisiboni Try removing '/' from `"/health"` for HealEndpoint.

Comment: Didn't works for me :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I successfully resolved my issue. The cause was a configuration of which hosts were allowed to access the health endpoint.

The issue was, that I restrict the access (in localhost) to port 5001, but the TestServer in the ApplicationFactory doesn't have any port.

Here is the configuration code

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">The application builder. <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/></param>
        /// <param name="configuration">The IConfiguration builder instance</param>
        public static void ConfigureEndpoint(this IApplicationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var healthConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(nameof(HealthConfiguration)).Get<HealthConfiguration>();
            builder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    // Prevent response caching
                    AllowCachingResponses = false,
                    ResponseWriter = (context, report) => context.Response
                        //Return an object instead of a plain text
                        .WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {status = report.Status.ToString()})),
                    ResultStatusCodes =
                    {
                        [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                        [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                        [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable
                    }
                }).RequireHost(string.Join(",",healthConfiguration.Hosts.Select(host=>host)));
            });
        }
```

Whereas the config section changed to

```
 "HealthConfiguration": {
    "Hosts": ["localhost"] 
  },
```